# Angular-UI Modal Error: Expected response to contain an object but got an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

First of all, I know this error has been covered many times around here, and I read thoroughly many questions about this but no one seems to fit my problem exactly. Why? Well most of them are not related to the Angular UI modal and the way it asks for the resources to display.

I'll start showing you my controller:

```
'use strict';

// Customers controller
angular.module('customers').controller('CustomersController', 
['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', '$filter', 'Authentication', 'Customers', '$modal', '$log',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $location, $filter, Authentication, Customers, $modal, $log ) {
         // Find a list of Customers
         $scope.find = function() {
            Customers.query(function (data) {
                $scope.customers = data;
                $scope.buildPager();
             });
         };

         // Find existing Customer
         $scope.findOne = function() {
              $scope.customer = Customers.get({ 
                   customerId: $stateParams.customerId
              });
          };

          //List Pager
         $scope.buildPager = function () {
             $scope.pagedItems = [];
             $scope.itemsPerPage = 15;
             $scope.currentPage = 1;
             $scope.figureOutItemsToDisplay();
         };

        /* Modal stuff */

        $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

        $scope.openUpdateModal = function (size, selectedCustomer) {

            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                templateUrl: 'modules/customers/views/edit-customer.client.view.html',
                controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, upcustomer) {
                      $scope.upcustomer = upcustomer;
                },
                size: size,
                resolve: {
                    upcustomer: function () {
                        return selectedCustomer;
                    }
                 }
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
                $scope.selected = selectedItem;
            }, function () {
                $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            });
       };

       $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
           $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
       };



//Controller Closing brackets    
    }
]);
```

In the view I have a list of customers, so if I click one of them I want the modal to open:

```
<a data-ng-repeat="customer in pagedItems" ng-click="openUpdateModal('lg', customer)" class="list-group-item"></a>
```

I did this thing based on a Bossable.com video tutorial called: [MEAN Stack: 20 - Pass Customer Details to an Angular UI Modal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVR7eilHJzE)

The only difference is that I got this error when clicking a customer:

```
 [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an object but got an array
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `$scope.findOne` function because it uses the get method and returns and array. If you look back at her tutorial, she kept it commented.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is to do with your Customer.query() or Customer.get() call. These are $resource calls and expect to be told what the response is.

Usually a **get** method expects an object while the **query** method expects an array. If you're not return one of those for those methods you need to configure it using the ***isArray: true/false*** option depending on your needs.

Documentation on this can be found:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

```
$resource( 'apiendpoint', {}, {
        query: {
            isArray: false
        }
    });
}
```